# How can I prevent web2py from automagically encoding html-entities?

Tags: html, markdown, web2py, html-entities

I'm trying to print out HTML generated for user-submitter `markdown`, by

```
{{=markdown(post.message)}}
```

where markdown function is imported through

```
from gluon.contrib.markdown.markdown2 import markdown
```

We2Py seems to automatically encode HTML-Entities, so every `<` is converted into `&lt;` and every `>` is converted into `&gt;`. How do I prevent this from happening?

Are there any security concerns that I'll need to keep in mind while doing so? Also, could anyone kindly tell me how can I strip the `HTML` when storing it in the database, while retaining the `markdown`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
{{=XML(markdown(post.message))}}
```

every string is sanitized by template render, if you pass  `"<div>"` it will be rendered as `"&lt;div&gt;"` it is to protect against malicious code.

When you pass a string to `XML` helper `XML("<div>")` it uses an `XML` parser to render the string in to an `XML` tree structure,`XML` has a method `.xml()` which returns the unescaped string to the `response.body` so the user's browser have the correct html.

you can control some parameters of `XML` rendering.

```
:param text: the XML text
:param sanitize: sanitize text using the permitted tags and allowed attributes (default False)
:param permitted_tags: list of permitted tags (default: simple list of tags)
:param allowed_attributes: dictionary of allowed attributed
```

Comment: What if a user submits a similar XML tree structure with a script? I mean how does web2py differentiate between its `XML` output and user-submitted ones?

Comment: Users can only submit text, and all text is escaped by default. The only way to avoid this is to pass the text to the web2py `XML()` helper class, which knows how to render itself without escaping. Users have no way to submit an instance of the `XML` helper class. Note, in this case, when we say `XML` helper, we mean a Python class called "XML", which is part of web2py, not a generic string that happens to be valid XML (if the user submits such a string, it will still be escaped).

Comment: Is there someway to set `permitted_tags` and `allowed_attributes` globally, so that I don't need to add them everywhere?
For now I'm using a function (`def my_xml(st): return XML(st, sanitize=True,...)`) imported in my models for global use